# Android: Saving a created bitmap to some equivalent of SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, bitmap

So I'm having the user create a profile, which includes an avatar. I would like the program to, like the user's name and other info, remember the avatar so it appears as their avatar whenever they use the app. I'd prefer for this bitmap to be saved when created, so the app doesn't need to rebuild the avatar (which is scaled and whatnot) each time the app is started. Is this possible? From the looks of it this wouldn't be able to be saved in SharedPrefs... any idea what the best way to do this would be? Thanks.

Followup: Followed CommonWares's suggestion. Saved to SD... but having trouble calling it back when the app is reloaded.

Currently, in onCreate:

```
String path = "testapp/images/thumbs/"+m_username+".jpg";
        File file = new File("testapp/images/thumbs/"+m_username+".jpg");
        if(file.exists()) {
            Log.e("TRY TO GET THUMB", "I EXIST");
            m_thumb = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
            Drawable draw = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), m_thumb);
            m_photoButtonE.setBackgroundDrawable(draw);
        }
```

Does not find the file, says it does not exist, though when I check my SD card the image is in that exact spot, with the proper file name and everything. Any ideas? Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Save it in a file.

> From the looks of it this wouldn't be able to be saved in SharedPrefs... any idea what the best way to do this would be?

Save it in a file. If you intend on having multiple avatar files, put a path to the saved avatar file in the `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: OK. Saved it to my SD successfully... check out my edited OP for a follow up Q. Thanks!

Comment: @JMRboosties: You didn't save the file to that path. In part, it would be because that's not the way to construct paths on Android. Use `new File(getFilesDir(), "testapp/...");` for a file on internal storage.